# Forwarding everything from external DMZ ip to NAT ip using iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

I know there are a lot of questions about this, but I still struggling to get it working.

I have a firewall which has 3 external IPs. (IPs have been changed randomly for security)

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:46:5d:64:ed:e4  
          inet addr:51.215.232.147  Bcast:51.215.232.159  Mask:255.255.255.240
          inet6 addr: fe80::5246:5dff:fe64:ede4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:70219084 errors:0 dropped:17443 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:63956103 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:51508818511 (51.5 GB)  TX bytes:27933240304 (27.9 GB)

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:46:5d:64:ed:e4  
          inet addr:51.215.232.148  Bcast:51.215.232.159  Mask:255.255.255.240
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth0:2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:46:5d:64:ed:e4  
          inet addr:51.215.232.150  Bcast:51.215.232.159  Mask:255.255.255.240
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

And I have these simple rules:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.10 on Sat Mar  3 14:48:42 2012
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [13766:4986720]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [992:122980]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [11894:5582822]
-A FORWARD -s 172.16.0.0/16 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -d 172.16.0.0/16 -i eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Mar  3 14:48:42 2012
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.10 on Sat Mar  3 14:48:42 2012
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [77:8206]
:INPUT ACCEPT [48:6367]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [55:3300]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [55:3300]
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.0.0/16 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE 
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.0.0/16 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE 
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.0.0/16 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE 
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Mar  3 14:48:42 2012
```

So I want to forward everything from 51.215.232.150 to internal IP 172.16.5.218.

So I thought this would work:

```
iptables  -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d 51.215.232.150 -j DNAT --to 172.16.5.218
```

But alas no.

Thanks in advance. 
Edward

Comment: Please do not use IP addresses that do not belong to you. IANA has set aside three IPv4 ranges (`192.0.2.0/24`, `198.51.100.0/24`, and `203.0.113.0/24`) and on IPv6 range (`2001:db8::/32`) for examples. You should use addressing from those ranges to obfuscate your real addressing so that we know they are example addresses, not addresses that belong to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would say that you need a corresponding FORWARD rule to actually allow the traffic through the FILTER table:

```
iptables  -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 172.16.5.218 -j ACCEPT
```

But your policy on the FORWARD table is already ACCEPT and there are no REJECT or DROP rules so it should go through OK.

Try adding a TRACE rule to see where the packet is going:

```
iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d 51.215.232.150 -j TRACE
```

Also, how are you testing? Can you see the traffic actually reaching the box?

```
tcpdump -lnn -i eth0 host 51.215.232.150
```